# FTP to a FTP server inside a LAN

Tags: ftp

I use FTP (actually use ipSwitch WS_FTP) quite a bit to shuffle stuff back and forth to my server at my web hosting company with no problem.

But now I want to FTP to a computer that is inside a LAN.  While I know the external I/P address of the router and I know that the internal computer running FTP services is 192.168.0.7 I don't know how to configure this.

How is this done?
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router has to be configured to forward inbound FTP connections to the internal address 192.168.0.7, and it must also provide a helper to manage the data channel (FTP uses 2 connections, not just 1 like most other protocols). A rather good explanation of how FTP works can be found [here](http://www.slacksite.com/other/ftp.html).

Comment: Can someone tell me what the voting is about?  I got a -1 vote on my question post.  Is someone grading me on the quality of my questions?

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) for the "vote-down" privilege. Your question isn't really on-topic here. It would have been more appropriate over at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). Also your description is rather vague, so someone apparently thought your question wasn't too useful.

Comment: -1 Whatever--I just needed to do the same thing... Here ya go. +1